# How to deploy SharePoint solutions using different versions of ajax extensions in a common SharePoint server?

Tags: 2007, ajax

We have a common SharePoint server which runs an internal SharePoint site. Our teams deploy their SharePoint products in the server and add it to our site. Some products user .net framework 2.0 and some products use .net 3.5. So they enable ajax extenisons for the site for .net 2.0 which adds the entries for the assembly System.Web.Extensions version 1.0.61025.0 where as our version will be 3.5.0.0. Because of the difference we get an ambiguous error while running the web site.

How can we deploy different products using different versions of Ajax extensions in the same site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend that your teams build all their products against version 3.5 of the .NET framework.

If necessary you can map DLL versions in your web.config file using [bindingRedirect](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/thottams/introduction-to-versioning-and-bindingredirect) to use the newer version of AJAX Extensions. You might need additional SafeControl entries if you have multiple versions.